# Date changes while exporting from sql server to csv using talend

Tags: sql-server, export, date-format, talend

I am exporting data from SQL Server in csv fle using Talend.
The date format I specified in tMap component is "YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000".
The date in SQL is 2015-04-28 00:00:00.000 which changes to 2015-04-118 00:00:00.000 in csv after export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Talend is just using the format patterns of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you want `yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000` - the problem you're seeing at the moment is that `D` means day of year, not day of month. That's why you're getting 118 - because April 28th is day 118 in a non-leap year.

Around the start and end of the year you'd also see problems because `Y` means "week-year" rather than year.

Comment: Ohhh...Thanks a lot ....actually I am unknown to Java...what could be done in my case where i have the yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000 format in sql server and the same i need to export as well....Please suggest....

Comment: @Meen: I don't know what you mean. I've told you what pattern to use for the export - you want lower case "y" and "d" rather than upper case. But hopefully your dates aren't stored in SQL Server as *strings* at all...

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jon....Yes you are right..after changing the case as suggested, its now working fine. My dates in SQL Server are stores as DATETIME....appreciate your help a lot.. Thanks again... :)